# Fan in Fan out problem

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, digital-communications, logic-level

Fan out is the maximum number of inputs that can be connected to a specific output. Why can’t we connect more number of inputs to this output?

Answer (score 1):

Fan out is a very essential factor because when the load exceeds the fan out the gate will not be able to drive the load at the designated current. This excerpt from wiki explains this better,

> An ideal logic gate would have infinite input impedance and zero output impedance, allowing a gate output to drive any number of gate inputs. However, since real-world fabrication technologies exhibit less than ideal characteristics, a limit will be reached where a gate output cannot drive any more current into subsequent gate inputs - attempting to do so causes the voltage to fall below the level defined for the logic level on that wire, causing errors.
>
> The fan-out is simply the number of inputs that can be connected to an output before the current required by the inputs exceeds the current that can be delivered by the output while still maintaining correct logic levels.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-out#Theory

Comment: It would be best if you didn't propagate nonsense form wikipedia.An _ideal_ logic gate would have infinite input impedance and zero output impedance but a real logic gate must deviate from this idealness.  What is ignored in wishing for ideality is that the existence of the device is due to the non-ideal characteristics, i.e. semi-conductors can be used because of thermal energy **not** in spite of.  A device that works in this way _must_ not be ideal.

Comment: So, what are you trying to say? That we shouldn't talk about idealness because nothing in the world is ideal..?

Comment: @placeholder: If you have a problem with Wikipedia, take it up with them, not here.

Comment: @RaghunathV: Don't forget that with CMOS logic, the load is primarily capacitive. Fanout also relates to getting the correct result *within the specified timing*.

Comment: @RaghunathV No, Ideality is very useful, to think about what the core functionality is. A perfect logic gate cannot exist, the wikipedia article is nonsense and I suspect you'd be more capable of writing something better.  The "less than perfect characteristics  .." are what allow the transistor to _Exist_ and transistors already have limited drive capability which in CMOS is an issue with _timing_.  Note carefully the useage of ideal and perfect.

Comment: @DaveTweed you're confused.  the issue is with accuracy and specious statements at wikipedia, we shouldn't be propagating that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a practical logic gate with output = '1'. This can be modeled as a voltage source \$V_{O}\$ in series with a resistance (\$R_O\$) (the thevnin's equivalent). For an ideal gate \$R_O\$ will be zero.

When a logic gate  is connected to the output of this gate, the input of that gate start to draw small current \$I_{in}\$ from the driving gate. Now the voltage obtained at the input of receiver gate is $$V_{in} = V_{O} - I_{in}R_O$$
When N such gates are connected, then,
$$V_{in} = V_{O} - N\times I_{in}R_O > V_{IH} \tag1$$

For detecting the input as logic '1' the receiver should receive a voltage greater than \$V_{IH}\$. But as N goes on increasing \$V_{in}\$ decreases and for some value of N (greater than *fan_out* of driving gate), \$V_{in}\$ will fall below \$V_{IH}\$ of the receiver gate. Then the output '1' may not be detected as '1' by the receiver.

In other words, for any gate there exists a maximum value of current, \$I_{Omax}\$, that it can source (or sink) such that the terminal voltage falls in the allowable range (noise margin). Such a gate can  drive a maximum of N gates each drawing a current of \$I_{in}= I_{Omax}/N\$. Connecting more gates can cause the receiver gates to receive *false* logic levels.